# Problem with accessing the layer legend using pyqgis in QGIS 2.4

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2.4

I'm trying to clear the layer selection using pyqgis.
It appears to me that:

```
lgd = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QtGui.QTreeWidget, "theMapLegend")
```

Doesn't work in QGIS 2.4 to access the layer legend.
Does anyone know a way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. To access the layer legend in QGIS 2.4, the following code can be used:

```
maplegendtree = qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow().findChild( QtGui.QTreeView, 'theLayerTreeView')
```

Answer (score 1):

The legend has been updated for QGIS 2.4. You should use the new API to access and manipulate the legend.

To clean the legend you can use the following code:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
root.removeAllChildren()
```

For more information read the following blog posts:

http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/
http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/